# Random color from array for GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, colors

Making a game in unity and I am using this code. I don't know what is wrong and why doesn't the sprite changes color when instantiated. Can you help so I don't lose my mind? :D (I am spawning random GameObjects as well)

```
int randomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, arrows.Length);
    GameObject prefab = arrows[randomIndex];
    GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0.02F, 2.18F, -1), Quaternion.identity);

    //change colors
    colors[0] = new Color (250, 250, 250);
    colors[1] = new Color (144, 249, 242);
    colors[2] = new Color (20, 173, 163);
    colors[3] = new Color (21, 129, 168);
    colors[4] = new Color (5, 95, 127);
    colors[5] = new Color (58, 125, 196);
    int colorRandomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, colors.Length);
    SpriteRenderer renderer = clone.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    renderer.color = colors[colorRandomIndex]; 
    myObjects.Add(clone);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try using

```
int colorRandomIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, colors.Length);

clone.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = colors[colorRandomIndex];
```

Okay so the error is the way you are creating your colors, [Color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) only accepts float values between 0 and 1. You need to use [Color32](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html)

```
colors[0] = new Color32 (250, 250, 250, 255);
colors[1] = new Color32 (144, 249, 242, 255);
colors[2] = new Color32 (20, 173, 163, 255);
colors[3] = new Color32 (21, 129, 168, 255);
colors[4] = new Color32 (5, 95, 127, 255);
colors[5] = new Color32 (58, 125, 196, 255);
```

Don't forget to also change the array to `Color32`

Comment: No it doesn't work. So this code works but it gives random colors. How could i change it so it would give colors from the array?
`clone.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = new Color(UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f), UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f));`

Comment: this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'a' of 'Color32.Color32(byte, byte, byte, byte)

Comment: @KlemenŠkrlj My bad you also need to add the alpha value of 255. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `renderer.material.color = colors[colorRandomIndex];`? It has been a while since I used Unity...

Comment: nope.. still uses it's original color. Do I have to change something in Inspector or something like that?